# Django ordering code in class

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I need a better solution to what I'm trying to achieve below. I have a form, this form needs to dictates the order of the **code** for the following items...

```
class ContactCSVModel(CsvModel):
    first_name = CharField()
    last_name = CharField()
    company = CharField()
    mobile = CharField()
    group = DjangoModelField(Group)
    contact_owner = DjangoModelField(User)
```

**For example...**

```
  class ContactCSVModel(CsvModel):
    if form.col1.value == "first_name":
        first_name = CharField()
    elif form.col1.value == "last_name":
        last_name = CharField()
```

**or maybe**

```
  class ContactCSVModel(CsvModel):
         [column.col1.value] = CharField()
         [column.col2.value] = CharField()
```

but this wont work as it will try to assign the value not make it first_name = CharField() etc

As you can see I end up doing this again for col2, col3 etc and end up with a '**lot**' of 'if statements'.

**Is there a better way, example?**

Thanks.

**Forms.py**

```
COL_CHOICES = [
    ('NONE', 'No Import'),
    ('first_name', 'First Name'),
    ('last_name', 'Last Name'),
    ('company', 'Company'),
    ('mobile', 'Mobile Number'),
    ('email', 'Email Address'),
    ]


class ConfiguratorForm(forms.Form):
    col1 = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=COL_CHOICES, initial='first_name')
    col2 = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=COL_CHOICES, initial='first_name')
    col3 = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=COL_CHOICES, initial='first_name')
    col4 = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=COL_CHOICES, initial='first_name')
    col5 = forms.TypedChoiceField(choices=COL_CHOICES, initial='first_name')
```

**This my untouched class as it is now:**

```
def import_data(column, *args, **kw):
    # make custom ContactCSVModel
    class ContactCSVModel(CsvModel):
        # IF column == x



        first_name = CharField()
        mobile = CharField()
        last_name = CharField()
        company = CharField()
        group = DjangoModelField(Group)
        contact_owner = DjangoModelField(User)

        class Meta:
            delimiter = ","
            dbModel = Contact
            update = {'keys': ["mobile", "group"]}

    return ContactCSVModel.import_data(*args, **kw)
```

Comment: Can you add more detail about what you're trying to achieve? I'm not sure what changing the order code appears in does for you. Also, having looked at the [Django model field reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/fields/) I can't find any such thing as a DjangoModelField.

Comment: I'm trying to do something like this  column.col1.value = CharField() but this just assigns the value, I want it to print the value like it was first_name = CharField() which is the value of col1

Comment: You mean you're trying to get your program to rewrite itself at runtime?

Comment: @cms_mgr yes, I have a reason don't worry about the reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you add the fields to the model afterwards, e.g.:

```
class ContactCSVModel(CsvModel):
    pass

for form_field in form:
    field_name = form_field.value
    model_field = CharField()
    model_field.contribute_to_class(ContactCSVModel, field_name)
```

For example (using Django 1.5):

```
from django.db import models 

class ContactCSVModel(models.Model): 
    pass 

for field_name in ('first_name', 'mobile', 'last_name'): 
    model_field = models.CharField() 
    model_field.contribute_to_class(ContactCSVModel, field_name) 

print [f.name for f in ContactCSVModel._meta.fields]

# prints:
[u'id', 'first_name', 'mobile', 'last_name']
```

Comment: what order will that do it in? it has to be in the order of col1, col2, col3.

Comment: `for form_field in form` will iterate over the form's fields in order (i.e. col1, col2, col3), so fields will be added to the model in the correct order.

Comment: setattr? would this not be better? contribute_to_class does not seems to work for me

Comment: `setattr` will not work, as quite a bit of work is done on a model class by its metaclass. Since we're adding fields afterwards, er need to duplicate this work. `contribute_to_class` should work on Django 1.5, which version are you using ?